# Windows 8.1 login with password AND fingerprint

Tags: windows-8.1, passwords, login, fingerprint

I have a Lenovo thinkpad w540 laptop running windows 8.1 which has a built in fingerprint reader. Is it possible to have windows require BOTH a fingerprint scan AND a password (not either one, but both at the same time) in order to login for extra security?

Comment: No;  Windows 8.1 only allows a single authentication.